# Visual Studio: how does VS decide to build a release or debug exe

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compiler-construction

I just created a new project configuration.

I named it 'Blah' So no 'debug' in it.

Now how does Visual Studio know when to compile a debug file or a release file.

is this merely defined by the DEBUG constant?

Or am I wrong? :)

Thanks

I'm using C#, with Visual Studio 2008.

Thank you for your answers.

I read that I need to define full debug info, how do I do that?

Short: if I define DEBUG, it's a debug build? Right?

Comment: To get full debug info select "full info" under *Properties -> Build -> Advanced -> Debug Info* (for C#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't compile a debug file or a release file; it compiles a Blah file. "Debug" and "Release" are just shorthand labels for a number of settings. E.g. the "Release" configuration includes optimization settings, whereas the "Debug" setting includes the generation of a PDB, and the preprocessor definition of `DEBUG`

Your Blah build configuration could be 50% debug, 50% release, if it mixes these settings. Some settings aren't even boolean, and thus your config could be unlike either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a simple Compiler Constant can control how your application is built.

You must know how to use configurations. See *Build Configurations* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa(VS.90).aspx.

> **Build Configurations**
>
> Build
> configurations provide a way to store
> multiple versions of solution and
> project properties. The active
> configuration can be quickly accessed
> and changed, allowing you to easily
> build multiple configurations of the
> same project.
>
> By default, and projects created with
> Visual Studio include Debug and
> Release configurations. Debug
> configurations are automatically
> configured for debugging an
> application, and Release
> configurations are configured for the
> final release of an application. For
> more information, see How to: Set
> Debug and Release Configurations. You
> can also create and edit your own
> custom solution and project
> configurations to meet the needs of
> your application. For more
> information, see How to: Create and
> Edit Configurations.